# Prefix results with string when exporting to LaTeX

Tags: org-mode

I have a source block whose code and results I would like to export to LaTeX:

```
    #+begin_src clojure :exports both
    (+ 1 2 3)
    #+end_src
```

I do `M-x org-latex-export-to-pdf` and get [image: LaTeX rendered from source block].
I would like the results to be prefixed by `=>`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by separating the export of the code from the export of the results:

```
#+name: example
#+begin_src octave :exports code
1 + 2 + 3
#+end_src
\Rightarrow call_example[:exports results]().
```

This uses the inline call feature for invoking named src blocks. Apologies for using octave; I do not have clojure installed.